# if else statement on window resize not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window

i have the following function

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function rows() {
        var divs = $(".film-list > li");
        wWidth = $(window).width();
        if (wWidth >= 1280) {
            for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
                divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
            }
        } else if (wWidth >= 600) {
            for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=2) {
                divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
            }
        }
    }
    rows();
    $(window).resize(rows);
    });
```

it works on page load but not on resize. no idea what's going on here, i've been banging my head against the wall with no solution. thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Missing brackets when calling the rows function inside the resize event.
Anyway, better to declare function outside the document ready and then call them inside.
Declare your function outside the document ready like this:

```
function rows() {
    var divs = $(".film-list > li");
    wWidth = $(window).width();
    if (wWidth >= 1280) {
        for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
            divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
        }
    } else if (wWidth >= 600) {
        for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=2) {
            divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
        }
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    rows();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    rows();
});
```